# find the user ids of users who like my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Do I need to find the user-id, from the username thats put like on the page that im admin.

For that reason ive generated a "non expiring" access token for my page with these permissions:

> manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, public_profile

But if I call the end point

```
/{page-id}?fields=likes
```

it gives me back this reply:

> ```
> "error":
> ```
>
> {
>         "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit
>   this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our
>   documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",

The first question is if that is the right endpoint to call to get the user that put likes on my page?

Second, is the right workflow to query all the user, then founds the one that that i need and to found his id?

Third if Im in the right direction, how can I make my apps review even if im far to be done....im only at the initial test... is it possible too to send it for review?
many thanks

Comment: the duplicate question is quite old, but still valid. you cannot get the users who liked your page. usually, people would need the list for something that is not allowed anyway. what is your use case?

Comment: tags some one in post, the post is create via my app, as merge of different documents written by the users that i'd like to tagged. imagine like a multi authors story thats need even to quote the authors so

Answer (score 1):

Calling `/{page-id}?fields=likes` is the same as `/{page-id}/likes`. According to the Facebook Docs, this is to retrieve the Pages this Page has liked. You cannot get the list of Users who have liked your page, only the total count of likes or new likes.

[image]

P.S. I don't get the same error as you as I've used a page I'm an admin off, with my app in developer mode. You don't need to get your app reviewed in this instance.

Comment: /likes for me works as expected not in the case that i've mentioned on the post... I dont know why. So for tagging a user in a post, i need is id, but his id is not anymore available right so?

Comment: why would you tag a user in a page post? what is the use case for this?

Comment: I agree with @luschn, you shouldn't be tagging users in page posts. This is the exact reason why this functionality was removed from the APIs.

Comment: tags some one in post, the post is create via my app, as merge of different documents written by the users that i'd like to tagged. imagine like a multi authors story thats need even to quote the authors so –

Comment: ok, that will definitely not be possible. you can only create an app for it and do this IN the app, with authorized users. you cannot use or get ANY user data without authorizing that user, no matter if he liked your page or not.

Comment: exuse me, if I found an user id trough an app like this one https://findmyfbid.com/ and then I add his Id to my post, it works! the app is real time app that recodrs users text and merge it as post... how can i do this without forcing users to be logged?

Comment: that page scrapes the user profile, which is not allowed on facebook. do not use that id and don't do scraping either.

Comment: so no way for doing like id like to do without loggin users on my app, or I wrong?